# Angular, select list first item is empty

Tags: html, angularjs

I am populating my select list like so -

```
<select class="selectLevel0" ng-model='scope1' ng-change='scope1Change()' 
            ng-options='obj.name for obj in array track by obj.id'>
</select>
```

Here is the $http behind it :

```
   //populate  scopes
    $http.post("/listScopes").success(function(data){
        $scope.array = data.scopes;
    });
```

What is happening is - I am getting a first select item that has no name and a value="?" (the rest populate fine). I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason is that since your ngModel is most possibly not assigned or not assigned properly with the id, angular creates a blank option and display that as selected.

You could either add a default option:-

```
<select class="selectLevel0" ng-model='scope1' ng-change='scope1Change()' 
            ng-options='obj.name for obj in array track by obj.id'>
 <option value="">Please choose a level</option>
</select>
```

Or set your ngModel with a default value in your controller or set it in `ng-init`. I would do it in the controller:-

```
 $scope.scope1 = "id"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the value of `scope1` is empty or undefined, if it's empty try to define it with `ng-init` or in controller.

Answer (score 1):

Angular by default creates a blank first selection to avoid accidental selection of an option. To remove this, set `scope1 = obj.name` where obj.name is the name of the first element in your array.