# Complex nested array to select boxes with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom-manipulation

I have an issue that I need to resolve, and am new to AngularJS. I've spent the night looking over videos, the official docs, and Googling as much as I can, to no avail.

Essentially what I have is some nested data in my controller, something like:

```
function SomeController($scope) {
  $scope.someArray = [
    {
      type: 'Dog',
      name: 'Sarah',
      children: [
        {
          type: 'Dog',
          name: 'Henry',
          children: [
            {
              type: 'Dog',
              name: 'Bob',
              children: []
            }
            . . .
          ]
        }
        . . .
      ]
    }
    . . .
  ];
}
```

Hypothetically, these *could* be nested infinitely deep. In reality, they rarely if ever go further than 2-3 levels deep. All the same, I'd like to write my code to handle this scenario, however rare it may be.

The way that this should work for the example above is: three select boxes, with the first option in each select box being something to the effect of "Select Something". Only the first select box should be enabled initially. Once something has been selected (in this example, our only choice is Sarah), then the second select box should be filled with Sarah's children and should be enabled. You can probably see how this proceeds.

Just to recap:

1. Select boxes at the root level should be pre-filled and enabled
2. Select boxes under the root level should be filled and enabled only once a selection has been made in its "parent" select box
3. This could *hypothetically* be infinitely deep

I have more or less accepted defeat at this point, after spending hours tinkering with it, I just cannot wrap my head around how to do this in AngularJS. All I have been able to get going was the root level. All of the other behavior is just a complete mystery to me. Do I need to use jQuery or something similar to fill the boxes? How do I access the array in my method to fill? Does AngularJS provide a good set of features that would ease my pain in any capacity?

I'd really appreciate some ideas and/or a point in the right direction.

**EDIT:** To make this even more complex (to me, anyway) is that the "type" is significant. In other words, if there were >= 1 objects on the root level, alongside Sarah, with type 'Cat', then all the cats need to go in a separate select box.

Comment: You are looking for something similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413071/how-to-handle-cascading-chained-dropdowns-using-multiple-ng-options#answer-25415189. http://plnkr.co/edit/AkmNSAdT4jctUqY8LPKD?p=preview

Comment: You need to make a directive for that. Maybe this can give you some hints: http://nickperkinslondon.github.io/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/test/bs3_ng120_test_page.html

Comment: Both of these are very helpful, thank you guys.